# Docker on windows locks folders (folder can't be deleted after being mounted to container)

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm having a problem with my docker/folders.
I'm using docker version 19.0.5 on windows VM and running a windows container to which I'm mounting a folder at run, the run command is executed from Jenkins job (bat(docker run -v ${WORKSPACE}:c:/app/ placeholder)) after the job is done (successful or not) I can't delete the mounted folder getting an error that is being used somewhere else.
I tried to stop the dockerd service or the Jenkins one etc. the only thing that releases the folder is a full reboot to the VM, any ideas on why or how I can combat this?
(when running docker volume ls there is nothing there)

Comment: If you type `docker ps -a` you'll see that the container still exists even if it's not running. That's why the folder is still considered as being used. In your run command, add the `--rm` option to tell the container to delete itself after a run so the attached folder should be unattached.

Comment: I didn't put the entire command (passing env variables etc.). I run it with --rm, and for testing, I tried "docker ps -a", and there is nothing there, and even if a container is still there (sometimes staid or didn't delete)after "docker rm" the folder is still locked.